# ERRO - Novo Projeto JAVAFX no NETBEANS 11

Tags: java, javafx

Estou tentando criar um novo projeto com **JAVAFX** no **NETBEANS 11.1** com o **UBUNTU 18.04**. Tentei de várias formas configurar, reinstalei JDK, alternei entre JDK 13 e OpenJDK, instalei openjfx, mas nada. A mensagem de erro que aparece é a seguinte:

> Failed to automatically set-up a JavaFX Platform. Please go to
>   Platform Manager, create a non-default Java SE platform, then go to
>   the JavaFX tab, enable JavaFX and fill in the paths to valid JavaFX
>   SDK and JavaFX Runtime. Note: JavaFX SDK can be downloaded from JavaFX
>   website.

Comment: ola, já seguiu este link ?
https://netbeans.org/kb/72/java/javafx-setup.html

Comment: Segui, até troquei para o JDK12, JDK11 OpenJDK e nada.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema, mudei para o Windows e realizei o mesmo procedimento de instalação JDK13+NETBEANS11.1, e não funcionou. Então tive a ideia de desinstalar o JDK 13 e instalar o JDK 8 + o Plugin do JavaFX SDK 2.2.7 e funcionou :).

Segue abaixo os plugins: 
Java FX 2.2.7 
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javafx2-archive-downloads.html
JDK 8
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html